# Why can't "i" be manipulated inside for-loop

Tags: python, for-loop

Why does:

```
for i in range(10):
 i += 1
 print(i)
```

return:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

instead of:

```
2
4
6
8
10
```

?

Here would be some details if any more were necessary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
for i in range(10):
    i += 1
    print(i)
```

is equivalent to

```
iterator = iter(range(10))
try:
    while True:
        i = next(iterator)
        i += 1
        print(i)
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

The `iterator` that `iter(range(10))` produces will yield values `0`, `1`, `2`... `8` and `9` each time `next` is called with it, then raise `StopIteration` on the 11th call.

Thus, you can see that `i` gets overwritten in each iteration with a new value from the `range(10)`, and not incremented as one would see in e.g. C-style `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

you should use steps in your range:

```
for i in range(2,11,2):
    print(i)
```

output:

```
2
4
6
8
10
```

Answer (score 2):

`i` is assigned at each loop iteration overwriting any changes done to its value.

```
for i in range(10):
    i += 1
    print(i)
```

is equivalent to:

```
 i = 0 # first iiteration
 i += 1
 print(i)

 i = 1 # second iiteration
 i += 1
 print(i)

 i = 2 # third iiteration
 i += 1
 print(i)

 # etc up to i = 9
```